# I love how you love me

Tags: grammar

Is this grammatical? Couldnt find an answer browsing web.Or do I have to say "the way you love me" ? I thought the way and how were pretty similar but doesnt look as this is the case. You cant say "I love how this looks." but I think "I love the way this looks" is fine. Now Im confused here because apparently a song is called like this as well so Id like to have an explanation as to why its possible here.

Comment: Do popular songs in your first language always use perfect grammar? This was a hit song by [The Paris Sisters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwGSKea-lGw) from 1961.

Answer (score 2):

> I love how you love me.

Though possibly an odd thing to say is grammatically correct.  You are saying how you greatly appreciate how someone shows their affection towards you.

> I love how this looks.
>   I love the way this looks.

are both correct, understandable and have the same meanings.

Comment: ok I thought it had to be "I love what this looks like." if anything (y sounds bad) since how refers to the way "this" "sees". The way is surely the best option here that I know for sure though.

Comment: @ChadThunder "Look" doesn't mean "see" here. It is used here as an _intransitive_ verb with the meaning of "to seem to the sight or to the mind" (OED.)

Comment: Alright but "I love how this smells" for instance is wrong isnt it? If you are talking about the smell not the smelling ability of "this". I remember seeing this kind ox explanation somewhere but I might be recalling it incorrectlh.

Comment: @ChadThunder No, it's not wrong. It's the same principle: in _I love how this smells,_ the verb "smell" (with apologies to S. Johnson) is _intransitive_ with the meaning _send forth, or exhale an odour_

Comment: Okay thanks now one last example. I know "Whats this song called" is fine but never hear someone say "How is his song called". Is this wrong if so why, does it sound bad? Whats the matter here?

Comment: @ChadThunder When "How is this song called?" is spoken, it's often a native Spanish speaker expressing _¿cómo se llama esta canción?_ "Call" is transitive here, in the passive voice, so it's really a different question. It's technically correct, but not idiomatic in English.

Comment: Technically correct in the sense that it has a meaning albeit a weird one? Does this refer to the process of calling it? f.e. by whistling lol? Sorry Im slow in understanding these things.

Comment: Because the questioner is asking for a name, the question is "what" not "how" in English, "What is this song called?"  Consider the difference between "What is this dog called?" vs "How is this dog called?" the first is asking for the name or type of the dog, e.g. Labrador, Springer Spaniel, German Shepard, the second is asking how to communicate with the dog e.g. voice commands, whistle commands, hand commands.  "What" tends to ask for a noun answer, "how" tends to ask for a verb answer.